# How to flip sprites horizontally with HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I am trying to make an animation with texture atlas:

[image]

and it works good when the Character is facing right. I try to flip it horizontally, but it gets wrong position:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="100" style="background: #000"></canvas>

var metaData = [
        {x:0,y:0,w:35,h:38,offsetX:3,offsetY:9},
        {x:37,y:0,w:31,h:37,offsetX:6,offsetY:10},
        {x:70,y:0,w:65,h:47,offsetX:0,offsetY:1},
        {x:137,y:0,w:65,h:47,offsetX:0,offsetY:1},
        {x:204,y:0,w:61,h:46,offsetX:1,offsetY:1},
        {x:267,y:0,w:42,h:46,offsetX:1,offsetY:1},
        {x:311,y:0,w:43,h:44,offsetX:1,offsetY:3},
        {x:356,y:0,w:38,h:37,offsetX:6,offsetY:10},
        {x:396,y:0,w:35,h:34,offsetX:6,offsetY:13},
        {x:433,y:0,w:33,h:37,offsetX:7,offsetY:10},
        {x:468,y:0,w:36,h:40,offsetX:5,offsetY:7},
        {x:506,y:0,w:34,h:39,offsetX:6,offsetY:8}
],
dx = 0, //position x
dy = 0, //position y
index = 0; //frame index

(function draw() {
    context2D.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

    var cur = metaData[index];

    if(facingRight) {
        context2D.drawImage(
            img,
            cur.x, cur.y,
            cur.w, cur.h,
            dx + cur.offsetX, dy + cur.offsetY,
            cur.w, cur.h
        );
    } else {
        context2D.save();
        context2D.translate(cur.w,0);
        context2D.scale(-1,1);
        context2D.drawImage(
            img,
            cur.x, cur.y,
            cur.w, cur.h,
            dx, dy + cur.offsetY,
            cur.w, cur.h
        );
        context2D.restore();
    }

    index = ++index % metaData.length;

    setTimeout(draw,100);
})();
```

I use `scale(-1,1)` to flip sprite, but I have no idea how to keep it at the same postion like facing right. Should I fix the offset value?

Please, any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: @Kaiido I make them the same size,  this texture atlas was packed by TexturePacker, it generates a JSON file, and I use the information to make the metadata.

Comment: I don't know this TexturePacker, but these are not textures, these are sprites. For ease of use, you need to align them, and set them is same sized invisible boxes. Currently they're not at all. They're not even y aligned. (character sprites are best bottom aligned)

Comment: @Kaiido I align them in PhotoShop, and packed by TexturePacker, it gave me correct position in JSON file like this:{
 "filename": "00.png",
 "frame": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":35,"h":38},
 "rotated": false,
 "trimmed": true,
 "spriteSourceSize": {"x":3,"y":9,"w":35,"h":38},
 "sourceSize": {"w":65,"h":49},
 "pivot": {"x":0.5,"y":1}
}, each frame is 65X49, it works good with facing right motion, except flip it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would save you a lot of time taking an Image editor and making all your sprites fit in same-sized areas along the whole sprite-sheet.

No need `metadata` weirdness, code is way simpler (a single `w`, a single `h`, `x = w * i` etc.

For example, your largest sprite is around 70px wide, so you should fit all your other sprites in one of such boxes :

[image: empty sprite-sheet with border]

Now, it seems that all your sprites share the same position of the front foot. So you should use it as the anchor point for aligning all your sprites.

Something like this :

[image: sprite-sheet with sprites and border]
Note how for all the sprites, the front foot is always at the same position relatively to its own box.

Now it's quite easy to code animation of this sprite-sheet, and even to flip it :

```js
const ssheet = new Image();
ssheet.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXKIc.png'; // same without borders
ssheet.onload = startSheetAnim;

function startSheetAnim(evt) {
  const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  const h = 49;
  const w = 70;
  let i = 0;

  function anim() {
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.drawImage(ssheet,
      (i * w), 1, w, h,
      0, 0, w, h
    );
    // scale (flip-x) and translate
    ctx.setTransform(-1, 0, 0, 1, w * 2, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(ssheet,
      (i * w), 1, w, h,
      0, 0, w, h
    );

    i = (i + 1) % 12
    setTimeout(anim, 100);
  }
  anim();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! But I still have a question, I get the sprites from some websites, they always pack the sprites and crop the transparent pixel, [this spritesheet](http://sprites-inc.co.uk/files/ZX/ZX1/Models/Model_HX/zx1_modelhx.png) reduce unnecessarily transparent area for the performance, can I use it directly or I have to re-position them?

Comment: In my mind it's easier to re-position them yes... I don't know why they packed it like that in the first place. If it's for image size, then they're doing it wrong : my sprite-sheet has a better compression than the one in your question and thus is lighter. Empty pixels don't weight too much in general, and you avoid the JSON.

Comment: Would that cause performance on GPU? Since there will be a lot of transparent area that is going to be rendered unnecessarily.

Comment: No not in a sensitive manner. You would have about the same gpu impact for less cpu one.

Comment: Really appreciated! I think I can take a lot from your experiences :)

Comment: @Kaiido you pack the sprites without spacing so you can fit many more sprites per sheet. This will reduce the number of sheets needed and increase per sprite rendering speed (this is significant performance factor on low end devices (phones/tablets/notebooks)). Each transparent pixel still needs to be addressed and read, even if the write is deferred it still needs GPU cycles that are better of writing other sprites. It is easy to create an extra 2 coords that are the offset to the normalised sprite size

Comment: @Kaiido I try to overlap the position of their feet with code `ctx.setTransform(-1, 0, 0, 1, w - offset, 0);` when flip it, which is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEBsD.png),  but I have no idea how to caculate the **offset**, finally I use **-15** to make it works. Would you mind helping me again? Thanks in advance.